# How to send direct email with DKIM enabled with nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, nodemailer, dkim

How can I send direct email via `nodemailer` with DKIM enabled?

I tried

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const directTransport = require('nodemailer-direct-transport')

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(
  directTransport({
    dkim: {
      domainName: "mydomain.com",
      keySelector: "mail",
      privateKey: "<generated private key>"
    }
  }))

require('express')().get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('sending mail')
  mailer.sendMail({
    from: 'support@mydomain.com',
    to: 'pmmEoRzqH5EyTO@dkimvalidator.com',
    subject: 'test email',
    html: 'Email content'
  }, (err, reply) => {
    console.log('email sent')
    console.log(err && err.stack)
    console.dir(reply)
  })
  res.send('test').end()
})
```

[I also added the public key as TXT record to my DNS panel.](https://lxadm.com/Generating_DKIM_key_with_openssl)

The email was sent but without DKIM as I checked at http://dkimvalidator.com/results

> DKIM Information: DKIM Signature
>
> This message does not contain a DKIM Signature

Is there anyone had succeed with this? This looks a straight forward cheap way to send email without setting up SMTP server but I did not see any post on this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I figured out my own solution.

`nodemailer` is big project but it looks lack of maintainer. Non-bug-report issue is closed by default.

I switched to [sendmail](https://github.com/guileen/node-sendmail/blob/master/examples/dkim.js) then everything works like a charm